# Cumulative Sum that resets based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, sum

Let's say I have the following data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Days':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                'Flag':["First","First","First","First","Second","Second","Second","Second"],
                'Payments':[1,2,3,4,9,3,1,6]})
```

I want to create a cumulative sum for payments, but it has to reset when flag turns from first to second. Any help?

The output that I'm looking for is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df['Flag'].ne(df['Flag'].shift()).cumsum()` to generate a grouper that will group by changes in the `Flag` column. Then, group by that, and `cumsum`:

```py
df['cumsum'] = df['Payments'].groupby(df['Flag'].ne(df['Flag'].shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Days    Flag  Payments  cumsum
0     1   First         1       1
1     2   First         2       3
2     3   First         3       6
3     4   First         4      10
4     1  Second         9       9
5     2  Second         3      12
6     3  Second         1      13
7     4  Second         6      19
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is you want since you didn't provide an output but try this

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'Days':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                'Flag':["First","Second","First","Second","First","Second","Second","First"],
                'Payments':[1,2,3,4,9,3,1,6]})
# make groups using consecutive Flags
groups = df.Flag.shift().ne(df.Flag).cumsum()
# groupby the groups and cumulatively sum payments
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(groups).Payments.cumsum()
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with

```
df['Cumulative Payments'] = df.groupby('Flag')['Payments'].cumsum()

   Days    Flag  Payments  Cumulative Payments
0     1   First         1                    1
1     2   First         2                    3
2     3   First         3                    6
3     4   First         4                   10
4     1  Second         9                    9
5     2  Second         3                   12
6     3  Second         1                   13
7     4  Second         6                   19
```